# SOAP - Can you modify a WebServices SOAP API by editing the WSDL file?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm scraping data from a website which has a WSDL WebService which I can access with a SOAP client. Heres the WSDL file:
https://www.ebi.ac.uk/webservices/chebi/2.0/webservice?wsdl

The problem is, the methods provided are too limited, which makes it really awkward to do what I need to do. Is there a way to add your own methods by editing the WSDL file (and loading it from your local server rather than the external server)?

I have a feeling this is a stupid question, that the WSDL file is only a map to coded functions located on the server, but I wanted to ask if theres any possible way to enhance the functionality provided by modifying the WSDL file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the WSDL file only describes the interface. Editing it won't give you additional functionality.